# What is an n-dimensional Riemann sphere called?

Tags: algebraic-topology, isometry

Is there a name for the ***complex manifold*** given by $z_i\overline{z_i}=1$ ? If indeed it is a complex manifold.

I know it is homeomorphic to the real manifold is $S_{2n-1}$.

Also, is it true to say that:

"The isometries are O(2n) and the 'holomorphic isometries' are SU(n)?"

Is that the correct language to use? (If it is true)

Comment: If the real dimension is odd, it simply cannot be a complex manifold.

Comment: For even dimensional cases, see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11664/complex-structure-on-sn) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1973/is-there-a-complex-structure-on-the-6-sphere).